# Ember.js Render multiple views inside static HTML

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm new to Ember and I'm stuck trying to render views.
The application in context is not a single page application but so far Ember has been playing nice until I started dealing with views.

I'm trying to render more than one view on a single page (which is like a dashboard and has tons of static HTML and a few containers, one for each view).

Sample HTML:
Let's say I would like to render two lists, one inside the "left-container" div and the other inside the right container.

```
<div class="static-header></div>
<!-- more static content goes here -->
<div id="left-container"></div>
<!-- more static content goes here -->
<div id="right-container"></div>
...
```

I've tried creating different views and inserting them using the `appendTo` method (which is described in the [Defining a View](http://emberjs.com/guides/views/defining-a-view/) section of Ember guides) but it throws the error:

> Container was not found when looking up a views template. This is most likely due to manually instantiating an Ember.View. See: http://git.io/EKPpnA

and I couldn't find my way using the link that it points to.

Ember code:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({});
App.HomeViewLeft = Ember.View.extend({    
    templateName: 'home-left',
});

var view = App.HomeViewLeft.create();
view.appendTo('#left-container');
```

I have also tried using a ContainerView as described in [Ember api docs](http://emberjs.joefiorini.com/api/classes/Ember.ContainerView.html):

```
App.HomeViewLeft = Ember.View.extend({    
    templateName: 'home-left',
});

var containerView = Ember.ContainerView.create({
classNames: ['container-view'],
});

containerView.pushObject(App.HomeViewLeft.create());
containerView.appendTo('left-container');
```

But I get the same error.

How should I render each view inside the #left-container and #right-container respectively?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Template:

```
<div id="here"></div>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/my-foo">
  {{text}}
</script>
```

JS:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

Ember.Application.initializer({
  name: 'stand-alone-components',

  initialize: function(container, application) {
    App.MyFooComponent.create({text: 'Hello World', container: container}).appendTo('#here');
  }
});

App.MyFooComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  init: function() {
    this._super();
    this.set('layout', Ember.TEMPLATES['components/my-foo']);
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nekowidera/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are trying to make views behave like [partials](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/#toc_the-code-partial-code-helper)

Move anything static into a partial and include it in your main template like so:

```
{{partial "header"}}
```

The lists you want to render can be turned into a [component](http://emberjs.com/guides/components/defining-a-component/) (if the only thing that changes in them is the data).

So you end up with a single view that contains partials and components:

```
<div class="static-header>{{partial "header"}}</div>
{{partial "static-content"}}
<div id="left-container">{{list-component data=firstList}}</div>
{{partial "static-content"}}
<div id="right-container">{{list-component data=secondList}}</div>
...
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this. Is it possible not to move static content into a template? There's so much of it that it feels more natural to leave it in the body and then add any dynamic content into it.
Is it possible to do this programatically?

Comment: Moving the static content into a partial is just for the sake of readability, you can keep it there

Comment: I probably didn't make my point clear. I was referring to not using a main template and leave it all inside the <body> tag of my page. This way I wouldn't need to pull out all the static content into a template. Is that possible? Thanks.

Comment: You could, but why would you? Are you sure that ember is the right tool for you? If you put them in the body they will persist throughout the entire site.

Comment: The thing is that the application is not a single page application, it's a traditional multi-page application, so the static content will only be available in the current page. So far all my app logic has reduced dramatically but views are getting a bit tricky.
If I put the static content in the body of the page, how could I "inject" dynamic content into it? Apologies for all the asking but I'm pretty new to Ember. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, would [rootElement](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#property_rootElement) be the thing you are looking for?